# jQuery same click event for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, events

Is there any way to execute same code for different elements on the page?

```
$('.class1').click(function() {
   some_function();
});

$('.class2').click(function() {
   some_function();
});
```

instead to do something like:

```
$('.class1').$('.class2').click(function() {
   some_function();
});
```

Answer (score 993, accepted):

```
$('.class1, .class2').on('click', some_function);
```

Or:

```
$('.class1').add('.class2').on('click', some_function);
```

This also works with existing objects:

```
const $class1 = $('.class1');
const $class2 = $('.class2');
$class1.add($class2).on('click', some_function);
```

Comment: To help developers remember this, even if a bit more extended using more psuedo classes it is the same format as applying a css selector when defining styles

Comment: What if had class2 cached like this var class2=$(".class2")?

Comment: @NeverBackDown `.add()` works with jquery objects too

Comment: Note that this will still attach events to jquery objects that exist, even if one of the selectors returns undefined.

Comment: can somebody explain what's the real difference between `$('.class1, .class2')` and `$('.class1').add('.class2')`? in what case we should use `.add()`?

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda `.add()` just adds another selector to an existing collection of elements.  you might use it if the two selectors came from different functions, for example, or if you were otherwise building a collection piecemeal.  i don't think i've ever used it myself.

Comment: NB: See [coolguys note](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7185280/823393) - *Make sure you put a space like $('.class1,**space here**.class2') else it wont work*

Comment: Using  this method $('#class1, #class2') with ids did not work for me, using the .add() worked like a charm. Thank you,  cheers!

Comment: I am asking a question that is not totally relevant to the op's question. but this is a discussion closest to my question. I found the *this* keyword inside the event handler, e.g. `some_function`, correctly points to the object if the selector is id based, e.g. $("#myid"), but points to a different thing, say, the container, if the selector is class based, e.g. $(".myclass"). Is that expected, or maybe I mid-observed/misunderstood something?

Answer (score 147):

I normally use `on` instead of `click`. It allow me to add more events listeners to a specific function.

```
$(document).on("click touchend", ".class1, .class2, .class3", function () {
     //do stuff
});
```

Comment: I like this way better. But can you target one element by class and one by ID in the same declaration? For e.g. $(document).on("click touchend", ".class1, #id1, .class3", function () {
     //do stuff
});

Comment: a year later: yes, you can! @GauravOjha

Comment: This technique--creating a delegated, rather than direct handler--also offers the unique advantage of handling events triggered by matching elements created *after* registering the handler. See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 49):

```
$('.class1, .class2').click(some_function);
```

Make sure you put a space like $('.class1,space here.class2') or else it won't work.

Answer (score 19):

Simply use `$('.myclass1, .myclass2, .myclass3')` for multiple selectors. Also, you dont need lambda functions to bind an existing function to the click event.

Comment: you need a space after the commas

Answer (score 11):

Another alternative, assuming your elements are stored as variables (which is often a good idea if you're accessing them multiple times in a function body):

```
function disableMinHeight() {
    var $html = $("html");
    var $body = $("body");
    var $slideout = $("#slideout");

    $html.add($body).add($slideout).css("min-height", 0);
};
```

Takes advantage of jQuery chaining and allows you to use references.

Answer (score 9):

If you have or want to keep your elements as variables (jQuery objects), you can also loop over them:

```
var $class1 = $('.class1');
var $class2 = $('.class2');

$([$class1,$class2]).each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        some_function();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

We can code like following also, I have used blur event here.

```
$("#proprice, #proqty").blur(function(){
      var price=$("#proprice").val();
      var qty=$("#proqty").val();
      if(price != '' || qty != '')
      {
          $("#totalprice").val(qty*price);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a comma separated list of classes like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.class, .id').click(function() { 

//  Your code

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a link to an object containig many input fields, which requires to be handled by the same event. So I simply use ***find()*** to get all the inside objects, that need to have the event

```
var form = $('<form></form>');
// ... apending several input fields

form.find('input').on('change', onInputChange);
```

In case your objects are one level down the link ***children()*** instead *find()* method can be used.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent examples and answers above, you can also do a "find" for two different elements using their classes. For example:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child1">Hello</div>
<div class="child2">World</div>
</div>

<script>
var x = jQuery('.parent').find('.child1, .child2').text();
console.log(x);
</script>
```

This should output "HelloWorld".