# combine multiple id into one event jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have three text field that needs to have a jquery click event

```
$('#landline' OR '#mobile_number' OR '#alternate_number').click(function()
{
$(this).val("");
});
```

I want this to implement whenever the user click the field with id landline or mobile_number or alternate_number the value will be set to null. but this code didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs? http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Or Simply you can assign same class for all the elements

Comment: Thanks for the comments, It has been solved. Thanks Thanks! :)

Comment: @madhairsilence IDs are faster though, as jQuery will map to the native getElementById()

Comment: yeh I agree, but we should also think about code maintenance. We cant have 100% optimized code all the time :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery same click event for multiple elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 4):

Use `,` to concatenate multiple selectors:

```
$('#landline, #mobile_number, #alternate_number').click(function() {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

Comment: yes that was pretty simple, Thanks! I never thought it would just be like this, I've been searching for an hour for this. haha I'm noob.