# Passing two elements to a function with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery function for a click event on a class:

JS

```
$('a[rel=blue]').click(function(){
    $('.ffHide').css("display", "none");
});
```

Now this works great, except I want to pass two classes to the function, how do I do that?

What I want to do:

```
$('a[rel=blue]', 'a[rel=black]').click(function(){
    $('.ffHide').css("display", "none");
});
```

but this does not work...

Comment: What you have coded is `$(element, context)` which selects the `element` within that `context`, combine your selectors and your code will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a[rel=blue], a[rel=black]').click(function(){
    $('.ffHide').css("display", "none");
});
```

Just a sidenote - you better use `.on()` for attaching event listeners, like:

```
$('a[rel=blue], a[rel=black]').on("click", function() {
    $('.ffHide').css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Zoltan. I assume you answered first right? Why the .on method?

Comment: `.on()` just for easier maintainability in the future if your app grows and you want to attach several listeners, i.e. `.on('click mouseenter focus')` or you want to remove the listener in some cases with `.off()` etc. And yes, first by a few seconds :)

Comment: thank you. How would I use the .off for undoing what I did with the click bind?

Comment: you can't undo with `.off()` what you've done with a click, but you can remove the event listener, so the element won't react to the click again - http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Personal question, how long did it take you to be as good in javascript/jquery as you are now?

Comment: I consider my knowledge of JS pretty beginner, but I think a year or two of dedicated learning/coding can do amazing things :)

Answer (score 2):

`'a[rel=blue]', 'a[rel=black]'` should be `'a[rel=blue], a[rel=black]'`.

```
$('a[rel=blue], a[rel=black]').click(function(){
   $('.ffHide').css("display", "none");
});
```

#### Multiple selectors will be separated by comma within a single quote.

#### Note

What you've tried is the `$(target, context)` format, which find the `target` element within the `context`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[rel=blue], a[rel=black]').click(function(){
  $('.ffHide').css("display", "none");
});
```

So close...

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('a[rel=blue], a[rel=black]').click
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[rel=blue], a[rel=black]').click(function(){
                $('.ffHide').css("display", "none");
            });
```

This should work

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as -

```
$('a[rel=blue], a[rel=black]').click(function(){
  $('.ffHide').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I was playing in fiddle... used toggle to see the result.. and by the time I posted the answer you already had many :)