# JQuery one click event for multiple element events

Tags: jquery

My question is related to this one:
[jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

However, when I do:

```
$('.class1, .class2').click(function() {
   some_function();
});
```

I always use the same function with the same object. What if I wanted to consolidate the following two statements for instance:

```
$(".class1").click(function () {
  $(".classer1").slideToggle("slow");
});

$(".class2").click(function () {
  $(".classer2").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

They reference a different object for each - can I even consolidate this?

Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: You could, but there's probably a better way to do it depending on the html structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$(".class1, .class2").click(function () {
  $(".classer"+$(this).attr('class').substr(-1)).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

as long as the elements you're clicking on only have one class. This pulls the integer off the element being clicked on and appends it to `.classer`. So clicking on `.class2` would trigger the toggle on `.classer2`.

Comment: Almost feels unfair to select ONE answer as they've all been great, but I like this idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is to add a data attribute to the reference number you are using for each of the classes so if you have something like

`<div class="class1" data-ref-id="1"></div>`

and

`<div class="class2" data-ref-id="2"></div>`

You could find your referenced toggle class like so:

```
$('.class1, .class2').click(function (e) {
    $('.' + NAME_OF_REFERENCED_TOGGLE_CLASS + this.data.refId).slideToggle('slow');
})
```

Comment: you should put that `e` in its place in the `function()`

Comment: But the OP wants to toggle other elements, not the ones clicked on. `.class1` vs `.classer1`

Comment: Exactly j08691 - that's the part I'm struggling with - toggling MULTIPLE items. Or is this possible with target and I don't get it?

Comment: Ah sorry I misread what was inside. I think my updated answer should help.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/). Use it to add selectors to the selection stack. Use it like this:

```
$('.class1').add('.class2').click(function (e) {
    // Do whatever you want
})
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?

Comment: maybe if he used `this` he will reference the object he clicked?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class='common-class' data-id='1'></div>

$('.common-class').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).data('id')) { 
        $(".classer" + $(this).data('id')).slideToggle("slow");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to select based on the elements location depending on your html. For example, if this were your html:

```
<dl class="class1 list">
    <dt>Foo</dt>
    <dd>Foobar</dd>
    <dt>Dog</dt>
    <dd>Pitbull</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="class2 list">
    <dt>Foo</dt>
    <dd>Foobar</dd>
    <dt>Dog</dt>
    <dd>Pitbull</dd>
</dl>
```

you could use:

```
$(".list dt").click(function(){
    $(this).next("dd").slideToggle();
});
```

to handle both lists with a single click event.