# Multiples checkboxes same .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Apologies for my lack of knowledge, I'm sure this is one of those simple fix solutions.

I have a number of checkboxes in my web page.
When you check a check box a value of 1 is sent to a variable.

See example:

```
  $('#abilitytobenonjudgemental').click(function(){ 
    var check = document.getElementById("abilitytobenonjudgemental").checked
    if (check == true) {
    job2 += 1;
    job3 += 1;
    job7 += 1;
    workSkillsCheckboxCount += 1;  
    console.log(workSkillsCheckboxCount);   
   }
    else if (check == false) {
    job2 -= 1;
    job3 -= 1;
    job7 -= 1;
    workSkillsCheckboxCount -= 1; 
    console.log(workSkillsCheckboxCount);

  }
   });
```

A number of the checkboxes' functions double up and I would like to write a big function, rather than a number of functions. 
This function below doesn't seem to work.

```
   $('#teamwork, #goodcommunicator, #self-motivated, #computerskills,      #planning, #selfmanagement, #flexibleteamplayer, #timedeadlines').click(function()     { 
       var check = document.getElementById("teamwork, goodcommunicator,      planning, self-motivated, computerskills, selfmanagement, flexibleteamplayer, timedealines").checked
     if (check == true) {
     job1 += 1; 
     job2 += 1;
     job3 += 1;
     job4 += 1;
     job5 += 1;
     job6 += 1;
     job7 += 1;
     job8 += 1;
     workSkillsCheckboxCount += 1; 
     console.log(workSkillsCheckboxCount);
 }
    else if (check == false) {
     job1 -= 1; 
     job2 -= 1;
     job3 -= 1;
     job4 -= 1;
     job5 -= 1;
     job6 -= 1;
     job7 -= 1;
     job8 -= 1;
     workSkillsCheckboxCount -= 1; 
     console.log(workSkillsCheckboxCount);

 }
 });
```

I tried giving the appropriate checkboxes a class and then wrote this function. But that doesn't seem to be sending the values to the workSkillsCheckboxCount variable.

```
  $('.group1').click(function(){ 
        var check = document.getElementsByClassName("group1").checked
    if (check == true) {
    job1 += 1; 
    job2 += 1;
    job3 += 1;
    job4 += 1;
    job5 += 1;
    job6 += 1;
    job7 += 1;
    job8 += 1;
    workSkillsCheckboxCount += 1; 
    console.log(workSkillsCheckboxCount);
}
    else if (check == false) {
    job1 -= 1; 
    job2 -= 1;
    job3 -= 1;
    job4 -= 1;
    job5 -= 1;
    job6 -= 1;
    job7 -= 1;
    job8 -= 1;
    workSkillsCheckboxCount -= 1; 
    console.log(workSkillsCheckboxCount);

}
});
```

Comment: kindly add [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In the function that does multiple checkboxes, are you trying to do `if (/*all of them checked*/){ ... } else {...}`, or `if (/*at least one checked*/)...`, or...?

Comment: If at least one are checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Comment: Could you please provide the associated HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.getElementById()` function takes a single ID as an argument and returns the (first) element with that ID (or `null` if none are found). You can't call it with a list of IDs.

Giving the elements a common class is the neatest way to identify them, but the `.checked` property belongs to individual checkboxes, so you can't use it on the results of `.getElementsByClassName("group1")` (which returns a list).

You said in a comment you are trying to test if at least one item is checked. jQuery's [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) will:

> *Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.*

So if you use that together with the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) you can test if any elements with the `group1` class are checked:

```
$('.group1').click(function(){ 
    if ($('.group1').is(':checked')) {
      job1 += 1;
      // etc.
    } else { // none are checked:
      job1 -= 1;
      // etc.
    }
});
```

Note that if both your `if` and `else` branches update exactly the same set of variables and the only difference is whether to add or subtract `1` then you can do something like this:

```
$('.group1').click(function(){ 
  var val = $('.group1').is(':checked') ? 1 : -1;
  job1 += val; 
  job2 += val;
  job3 += val;
  job4 += val;
  job5 += val;
  job6 += val;
  job7 += val;
  job8 += val;
  workSkillsCheckboxCount += val;
  console.log(workSkillsCheckboxCount);   
});
```

Comment: The first funciton worked. Thank you so much! You have literally saved the day :D

Comment: Hmm, the function doesn't seem to be subtracting the value of 1 when I uncheck the box, it keeps adding more values.

Comment: What do you mean by "the box"? You have multiple boxes, and if you uncheck one then the code shown will add (not subtract) if at least one other box is (still) checked - you said in a comment the other day you want to do stuff "if at least one are checked".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```js
$(".check").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    // do your checked activity here
    
    // if your further want to know which checkbox was checked recently then $(this).attr('name') will be handy
    console.log("Checkbox "+$(this).attr('name')+" checked: true");
  } else {
    // do your unchecked activity here
    
    // if your further want to know which checkbox was unchecked recently then $(this).attr('name') will be handy
    console.log("Checkbox "+$(this).attr('name')+" checked: false");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="check" name="c1" type="checkbox" />
<input class="check" name="c2" type="checkbox" />
<input class="check" name="c3" type="checkbox" />
<input class="check" name="c4" type="checkbox" />
<input class="check" name="c5" type="checkbox" />
<input class="check" name="c6" type="checkbox" />
```