# jQuery event handler on multiple element variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is something like this possible?
I have multiple variables set to DOM elements. Instead of hitting the DOM again to get set the event handlers, I want to use the variables I already have set.

```
var a = $("#foo");
var b = $("#bar");

a,b.on("click", function() {

});
```

Comment: I guess this helps answering your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 2):

### Solution #1

You can use `.add()` to chain the cached elements.

```js
var a = $("#foo");
var b  = $("#bar");

(a).add(b).on("click", function() {
  alert('Handler registered');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="foo">Foo</button>
<button id="bar">Bar</button>
```

### Solution #2

When you are dealing with multiple cached elements, a more elegant solution would be, as Barmar suggests, to pass them as an array to `$()`.

However, take care to pass in only the **first item** of the cached jQuery object so that you are actually targeting the DOM element itself, not the jQuery wrapper object.

```js
var a = $("#foo");
var b = $("#bar");
var c = $("#biz");


$([a[0], b[0], c[0]]).on("click", function() {
  alert('Handler registered');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="foo">Foo</button>
<button id="bar">Bar</button>
<button id="biz">Biz</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can use the same notation as in CSS to afect multiple elements, just separate them using a comma.

```
$('#foo, #bar').on("click", function () {})
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about using variables for the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array as the argument to `$()` and it will create a new collection of everything in it. It doesn't hit the DOM again.

```
$([a, b]).on("click", function() {
    ...
});
```

However, it requires that the array contain DOM elements, not jQuery objects. You can turn a jQuery collection into an array of the elements with `.get()`. Since you'll get nested arrays, you can then use `.flat()` to flatten this. For ID selectors this isn't really needed, since you could just select the first element with `.get(0)`, but the method below generalizes to collections of multiple elements.

```js
var a = $('#foo');
var b = $('#bar');

$([a.get(), b.get()].flat()).on("click", function() {
    alert('Does this work?');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="foo"> Foo </button>
<button id="bar"> Bar </button>
```