# jQuery function to avoid copy/paste

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery to load `div` content by year (from 2008 to current year).

Here is my code :

```
$('.filtre .f2017').click(function() {
    $('.loader').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
    $('.selected .homeliVa li').hide('slow');
    $('.homeliDp .itemCom').hide('slow');
    $('.selected .homeliAlm li').hide('slow');
    setTimeout('$(".selected .annee2017").show()', 5000);
    $('.selected .nothing').show('slow');
    $('.loader').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
    $('.filtre .date').removeClass('selectedF');
    $('.filtre .f2017').addClass('selectedF');
    $('.selected .itemCom').removeClass('selectedItem');
    $('.selected .annee2017').addClass('selectedItem');
});

[...]

$('.filtre .f2008').click(function() {
    $('.loader').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
    $('.selected .homeliVa li').hide('slow');
    $('.homeliDp .itemCom').hide('slow');
    $('.selected .homeliAlm li').hide('slow');
    setTimeout('$(".selected .annee2008").show()', 5000);
    $('.selected .nothing').hide('slow');
    $('.filtre .date').removeClass('selectedF');
    $('.filtre .f2008').addClass('selectedF');
    $('.selected .itemCom').removeClass('selectedItem');
    $('.selected .annee2008').addClass('selectedItem');
});
```

So I copy/paste my first `.click` function for every year.

**EDIT**

Here is generated HTML :

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'post_type'=> 'dp',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
while( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    [...]
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $post->guid ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    <h3>
       <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $post->guid ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>">
          <?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() ); ?>
       </a>
    </h3>
   [...]
```

And HTML output from DOM for only une item :

```
<div id="post-16351" class="itemCom annee2014 selectedItem" style="display: block;">
    <div class="postHeader">
        <h3>
            <a href="url" title="title">
                Post title
            </a>
        </h3>
        <div class="postMeta">
            <ul class="styles">
                <li class="term_id">
                    <a href="url" rel="tag">Term name</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span>Publié le : 17 décembre 2014</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fichiersDp">
        <a class="download-link filetype-icon fichier-pdf" target="blank_" href="url">name_of_file_attachment</a>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Is it possible to have a loop or something else to avoid the copy/paste and return `current year`.
Problem is that every year, I should copy/paste for new year.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, specially HTML code

Comment: HTML is generated by function. This function return every post from a specific year and specific post type. My code works, i just want to avoid copy/paste :)

Comment: We cannot help you effectively without seeing the HTML. Just copy/paste it from the output if it's auto-generated

Comment: Why not create an array for years and iterate through the array to get all the years?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Comment: Edited with HTML output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have div to click with `id` or `class` you can try :

```
$('.filtre .yourClass').click(function() {
    var item = $( this ).find('.class').text(); //If the text "button" is `2017` for example, this will return `2017`
    $('.loader').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
    $('.selected .homeliVa li').hide('slow');
    $('.homeliDp .itemCom').hide('slow');
    $('.selected .homeliAlm li').hide('slow');
    setTimeout($(".selected .annee" + item).show(), 5000);
    $('.selected .nothing').hide('slow');
    $('.filtre .date').removeClass('selectedF');
    $('.filtre .f' + item).addClass('selectedF');
    $('.selected .itemCom').removeClass('selectedItem');
    $('.selected .annee' + item).addClass('selectedItem');
});
```

`var item = $( this ).find('element or .div').text();` allow you to recover the date.

Comment: I replaced `.yourClass` by common class `.date` and `.class` by `a` and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make a loop that starts at a certain year and finishes at a certain year. And insert the year into the template like so:

```
for (var year = 2000; year < 2008; year++) {

    $('.filtre .f' + year).click(function() {
        $('.loader').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
        $('.selected .homeliVa li').hide('slow');
        $('.homeliDp .itemCom').hide('slow');
        $('.selected .homeliAlm li').hide('slow');
        setTimeout('$(".selected .annee' + year + '").show()', 5000);
        $('.selected .nothing').show('slow');
        $('.loader').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
        $('.filtre .date').removeClass('selectedF');
        $('.filtre .f' + year).addClass('selectedF');
        $('.selected .itemCom').removeClass('selectedItem');
        $('.selected .annee' + year).addClass('selectedItem');
    });
}
```

You could do the same thing with an array:

```
var years = [2000, 2008, 2010]
years.forEach(function(year) {
    // same template as above in here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var years = [2017, 2008] //put all needed years in array

for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  $('.filtre .f' + years[i]).click(function() {
      $('.loader').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
      $('.selected .homeliVa li').hide('slow');
      $('.homeliDp .itemCom').hide('slow');
      $('.selected .homeliAlm li').hide('slow');
      setTimeout('$(".selected .annee" + years[i]).show()', 5000);
      $('.selected .nothing').hide('slow');
      $('.filtre .date').removeClass('selectedF');
      $('.filtre .f' + years[i]).addClass('selectedF');
      $('.selected .itemCom').removeClass('selectedItem');
      $('.selected .annee' + years[i]).addClass('selectedItem');
  });
}
```

Comment: Works, but always display 2008 when i click on another date

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you could add a data attribute or similar to each relevant element containing the unique year identifier e.g: `data-filtre-year="2008"` - Then using that data attribute as selector you can bind the event.

```
$('.filtre [data-filtre-year]').click(function() {
    var $currentElement = $(this);
    var anneeClass = '.annee' + $currentElement.data('filtreYear');

    $('.loader').show().delay(7000).fadeOut();
    $('.selected .homeliVa li').hide('slow');
    $('.homeliDp .itemCom').hide('slow');
    $('.selected .homeliAlm li').hide('slow');
    setTimeout('$(".selected ' + anneeClass + '").show()', 5000);
    $('.selected .nothing').hide('slow');
    $('.filtre .date').removeClass('selectedF');

    $currentElement.addClass('selectedF'); // as you are already in the context of the element you can use "this"

    $('.selected .itemCom').removeClass('selectedItem');
    $('.selected ' + anneeClass).addClass('selectedItem');
});
```