# How To call the same Method for different Elements with different IDs?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say i have 3 p-Elements. If i click on one of them its Text should change. But how can i do it without writing a Method for every Element?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>

<p id="demo">Click me.</p>
<p id="demo2">Click me.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example if i click on the first one it works. But not for the second one. And i dont want to write the same method over and over and just change the Ids. There must be a more simple way. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Comment: No, this is not jQuery, and should not be treated as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks guys for the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Get the element via `Event.target` and pass it to your function:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function(event) {
        myFunction(event.target)
    };

    function myFunction(element) {
        element.innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That was very helpfull!

Comment: @NiceMice Always glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the same listener on the multiple element, I would advice using class instead of ids

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll(".selector");
p.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', myEventHandler);
})

function myEventHandler(event) {
    event.target.innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
```

```html
<p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>

<p class="selector">Click me.</p>
<p class="selector">Click me.</p>
```

Comment: Using classes is the best answer. And at this point it's pretty safe to assume that `this` will be set to the triggering event within the handler, but historically that was not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, elements shouldn't have the same id.

Second, have your function accept a parameter for the event. This will let you get the thing that you clicked on.

Third you just want to set some text so switch out `innerHTML` for `textContent`.

```html
<p id="demo">Click me.</p>
<p id="demo2">Click me.</p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("demo").onclick = myFunction;
    document.getElementById("demo2").onclick = myFunction;

    function myFunction(e) {
        e.target.textContent = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple elements should not have same `id` attribute. But you can have same `class` for multiple elements.

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to get all the targeted `p`. Then you can add the `click` event to each `p` with `forEach()` and `addEventListener()`. Inside the function you can access the currently clicked element with keyword `this` like the following way:

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll(".demo");
p.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
})

function myFunction() {
    this.innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
```

```html
<p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>

<p id="demo1" class="demo">Click me.</p>
<p id="demo2" class="demo">Click me.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in all of them and use `document.querySelectorAll(".p");` to add event listeners for all of them

```js
var o = document.querySelectorAll(".p");

for(var i=0; i<o.length; i++){

    o[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
      e.target.innerHTML = "You clicked ME"
    
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>

<p id="demo" class="p">Click me.</p>
<p id="demo2" class="p">Click me.</p>

 

</body>
</html>
```