# Multiple OR conditions in Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use multiple form ids inside a javascipt function, but it doesn't work. The code is:

```
    $('#Rate1').keyup(function(){
    var Amt1;
    var Amt2;
    var Amt3;
    var Amt4;
    textone = parseFloat($('#Amt1').val());
    texttwo = parseFloat($('#Amt2').val());
    textthree = parseFloat($('#Amt3').val());
    textfour = parseFloat($('#Amt4').val());
    var result = textone + texttwo + textthree + textfour;
    $('#TotalInvoiceValue').val(result.toFixed(2));


});
```

And I want to use multiple ids like this:

```
$('#Rate1' || '#Rate2' || '#Rate3' || '#Rate4').keyup(function(){
    var Amt1;
    var Amt2;
    var Amt3;
    var Amt4;
    textone = parseFloat($('#Amt1').val());
    texttwo = parseFloat($('#Amt2').val());
    textthree = parseFloat($('#Amt3').val());
    textfour = parseFloat($('#Amt4').val());
    var result = textone + texttwo + textthree + textfour;
    $('#TotalInvoiceValue').val(result.toFixed(2));


});
```

But it's not working. Please point out what I am doing wrong here..

If you have a better suggestion to use something other than keyup is also welcomed.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just want to assign the same event handler to multiple selectors.

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Try using comma ',' instead of logical or '||'

I.e

```
$('#Rate1, #Rate2, #Rate3, #Rate4').keyup(function(){
var Amt1;
```

Comment: Alternatively, give the elements a shared class (like `class="rate"`) and use the class as your jQuery selector: `$('.rate')`

Comment: @JonUleis Hi can you show how I can assign multiple elements in a class?

Comment: @CodyCoderson I just did! If you included some HTML I could point it out better.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer answers your question exactly. But as the comments mention, using classes can simplify things and is more flexible.

html

```
<input id="Amt1" class="rate" type="text">
<input id="Amt2" class="rate" type="text">
<input id="Amt3" class="rate" type="text">
<input id="Amt4" class="rate" type="text">
```

javascript

```
$('.rate').on('keyup', function() {
  let result = 0;
  $('.rate').each(function() { result += parseFloat(this.value); });
  $('#TotalInvoiceValue').val(result.toFixed(2));
})
```