# JQuery capture two different events on two different elements to run the same function

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery, I have two *different* events on two different elements, that I want to trigger the same function. Is there some way to combine the two separate statements into one statement -

Example:

```
$('#element1').on('change', function () {
      myFunction();
});

$('#element2').on('click', function () {
      myFunction();
});
```

Is there someway to combine these into one statement?

I would like to do something *like* -

```
//this does not work
$('#element1','#element2').on('change, click', function () {
      myFunction();
});
```

**NOTE**:

- The event 'change' should *ONLY* apply to '#element1'
- The event 'click' should *ONLY* apply to '#element2'.
- The event 'change' should *NOT* apply to '#element2'
- The event 'click' should *NOT* apply to '#element1'.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that exactly what you have in the first code block?

Comment: The first code block in my question has two separate statements, I want to combine them into one, such as in my second code block, but that code does not work.

Comment: You can [bind a function to multiple events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534089/jquery-multiple-events-to-trigger-the-same-function) and you can [trigger the same function for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements), so you could put these together with some conditional logic to trigger the appropriate function for each element but it seems like more overhead than just binding the specific event to the element you want to trigger the function for in the first place.

Comment: It may help if you can you explain the reason for your requirement?  Is it purely educational or is there a deeper reasoning?  eg is this intended to apply to 1000s of controls?

Comment: What's your definition of "one statement"?  You can use `,` which will still be one statement, eg: your original code as "one statement": `$('#element1').change(myFunction),$('#element2').click(myFunction);`

Comment: The purpose of this is for "Click a submit button" and "Change a drop down list" should trigger the same function, which is remove a validation error from the screen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done.

```
$('#element1, #element2').on('click change', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (($this.is('#element1') && event.type === 'change') ||  ($this.is('#element2') && event.type === 'click')) {
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this should Work, but I think the oruginal code is more elegant.

Comment: @PoulBak I totally agree. I don't understand _why_, you would want this, but it can be done and I believe this to be the shortest version. One could also change the first argument of `on` into an object, with the events as keys, but that just gives you basically the same.

Comment: The purpose of this is for "Click a submit button" and "Change a drop down list" should trigger the same function, which is remove a validation error from the screen..