# Trigger same function on different events of different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

What I am looking for is a way to register same function (event handler) for  different events of different elements. For example, I want to call a function in `click` event of a button + `submit` event of a form.

There are two related-similar solutions ([jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements) and [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)), However, they are not exactly what I want.

It is possible to register events individually, or chain events together (on form's `submit` event, call button's `click` event) but I wonder if it is possible to do it with one event registration/statement.

Comment: Create a function and use a reference to the function when attaching events. Like `$('form').on('submit', fn); $('button').on('click', fn);`.

Comment: Or use event delegation. Give a common class name (or some other identifier) to the elements sharing the events, then `$(closestCommonAncestor).on('submit click', '.commonClass', fn);`.

Comment: @Teemu: I think the second suggestion has overheads and may doesn't make sense; since `submit` is not defined for button and vice versa.

Comment: That's what you've asked ..? "_Trigger same function on different events of different elements ... with one event registration_". Note that the event attaching won't fail nevertheless the event doesn't exist on an element, the event(s) are just not attached to those elements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need JQuery for this. You can do this with plain JS. Just create a function and then use it as callback.

```js
   const cb = () => {
     //implementation of your goes here
   };

   const elem = document.getElementById('yourElemeId'); //select your element
   elem.addEventListener('click', cb);
   const elem2 = document.getElementById('yourElemeId2'); //select 2d element
   elem2.addEventListener('submit', cb)
```