# Is there a way to only have one function in jQuery handling all HTML buttons?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a price calculator and want to calculate the price depending on the button selected. I'm also looking for a way to do this with only one function instead of having onclick function for every single button.

I have tried creating an onclick event for every single button, but that was not the way to go as the document was full of pointless functions.

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" style="margin: auto;">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Počet vodivých vrstev</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">6</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect to use only one function for all these buttons and only read the button value and work with it afterwards.
I have been using onclick for every single button so far, but it was not the way to go, because the document ended up being full of functions containing only one line which I think is possible with only one function, instead of having a huge amount of functions and click events.
I also expect the button to change the total product price contained in a variable named $currentPrice, which I am updating on change and click events, so it only has to edit the variable $currentPrice.

Comment: `$("button").click(....` probably want to be more specific though and give all the "same" buttons a new class and attach to that `$("button.myclass").click(...` or `$(".calc>button")....` - but your HTML (*as provided*) raises the question: How are you doing this one button at a time?  As they don't have an ID or different class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing same calculations for the buttons but only different values as you mention:

> *I expect to use only one function for all these buttons and only read
>   the button value and work with it afterwards.*

You can do:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
$(".rates").html("rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*150);
});
```

```css
.rates {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" style="margin: auto;">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Počet vodivých vrstev</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">6</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rates">
</div>
```

**BUT** if your calculations are different for each button you can do something like:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
switch($(this).text()) {
case "1":
$(".rates").html("good rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*150);
break;
case "2":
$(".rates").html("better rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*200);
break;
case "4":
$(".rates").html("best rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*150);
break;
default:
$(".rates").html("normal rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*100);
}
});
```

```css
.rates {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" style="margin: auto;">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Počet vodivých vrstev</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">6</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rates">
</div>
```

**FOR YOUR COMMENT:**

NOTICE how I have added **group-1** and **group-2** classes to the container divs and how I changed the click functions from button to **group-1 button** and **group-2 button**. I also changed the changed the id of second span to **inputGroup-sizing-sm2** because ids must be unique and one per page.

Check out this:

```js
$(".group-1 button").click(function() {
switch($(this).text()) {
case "1":
$(".rates").html("FROM 1-ST GROUP good rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*150);
break;
case "2":
$(".rates").html("FROM 1-ST GROUP better rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*200);
break;
case "4":
$(".rates").html("FROM 1-ST GROUP best rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*150);
break;
default:
$(".rates").html("FROM 1-ST GROUP normal rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*100);
}
});
$(".group-2 button").click(function() {
switch($(this).text()) {
case "1":
$(".rates").html("FROM 2-ND GROUP good rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*150);
break;
case "2":
$(".rates").html("FROM 2-ND GROUP better rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*200);
break;
case "4":
$(".rates").html("FROM 2-ND GROUP best rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*150);
break;
default:
$(".rates").html("FROM 2-ND GROUP normal rates for " + $(this).text() + " Počet vodivých vrstev are: $" + $(this).text()*100);
}
});
```

```css
.rates {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar">
    <div class="group-1 btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" style="margin: auto;">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Počet vodivých vrstev</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">6</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="btn-toolbar mb-3" role="toolbar">
    <div class="group-2 btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group" style="margin: auto;">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm2">Počet vodivých vrstev</span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-form">6</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rates">
</div>
```

Comment: This I suppose is the best solution to figure this out. And let's say I have more blocks with multiple choices and I only want one choice per block. What would it require to write? Because in this case, I can only have one button active.
Imagine the same block (section or however you call it) as I posted above "Počet vodivých vrstev", but with a different name and different values also with only one choice available, but not colliding with the first block, only affecting the total price.

To make it more understandable, I am sending a URL of image of my HTML theme
https://ctrlv.cz/SI6F

Comment: I am sorry, the URL posted seems to not work, so here I am posting a new one
https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2019/11/01/j4NX.png

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer read everything after FOR YOUR COMMENT:

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).  While the answers here work, they may be highly coupled and hard to extend.

I would create a specific class for this functionality and then add data attributes to control what data (text) changes and what (target) element(s).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-change-text').on('click', function() {
    var src$ = $(this);
    var target = src$.data('target');
    var target$ = $(target);
    var text = src$.data('text');
    target$.text(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Div 1 Change A" data-target=".div1" data-text="Change A Text" class="js-change-text"/>
<input type="button" value="Div 1 Change B" data-target=".div1" data-text="Change B Text" class="js-change-text"/>
<input type="button" value="Div 1 Change C" data-target=".div1" data-text="Change C Text" class="js-change-text"/>
<input type="button" value="Div 2 Change A" data-target=".div2" data-text="Change A Text" class="js-change-text"/>
<input type="button" value="Div 2 Change B" data-target=".div2" data-text="Change B Text" class="js-change-text"/>

<div>Div 1 <span class="div1"></span></div>
<div>Div 2 <span class="div2"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".btn-form").click(function() {
var clickedButtonTxt = $(this).text();
samefunction(clickedButtonTxt);
});

function samefunction(clickedButtonTxt){
//Do your stuff for each button
}
```

And if you want to target multiple buttons with different classes you can seperate your selectors with a comma like this.

```
$(".btn-form, .btn2, .btn3").click(function() {
...
)};
```