# Java Script function link combine issue in my case

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have issue in flask project, i need set up two js with one link if both was clicked or checked.
For example my data table do changes if clicked check box or selected from multi select some options.

But need make them both if selected and clicked (can be only selected or only just clicked). But need make and option for both
For make issue more clearly after get checked send value in the python function.
I think problem with `url`.

My js code.

```
  //  MULTISELECT
  
    $('.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
      selectedServices = $(this).val();
      alert(selectedServices)
      var url = '/api/VERSION/DATABALE/get?groupFilter='+ selectedServices
      console.log('new URL'+url);
      table.ajax.url(url).load();
      table.ajax.reload();


    });


// CHECK BOX
  $('input[name="checkboxGroup1"]').on("click", function(){
  console.log("Filter clicked")
  var own = false;
  var own = false;
  // var id = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  if($('#own').is(":checked")) { var f_own = true;} 
  else { var f_own = false; }
  if($('#research').is(":checked")) { var f_research = true;} 
  else { var f_research = false; }

  var url = '/api/VERSION/DATABALE/get?f_own='+ f_own +'&f_research='+ f_research
  console.log('new URL'+url);
  table.ajax.url(url).load();
  table.ajax.reload();
});
```

So need somehow combine this js. IF only selected options send this `selectedServices` if checked checkbox send only `values` from `checkbox` js. IF selected or clicked both send both values.

I try combine like this

```
$('.selectpicker').on('change'); or ('input[name="checkboxGroup1"]').on("click", function(){
  selectedServices = $(this).val();
  console.log("Filter clicked")
  var own = false;
  var research = false;
  if($('#own').is(":checked")) { var f_own = true;} 
  else { var f_own = false; }
  if($('#research').is(":checked")) { var f_research = true;} 
  else { var f_research = false; }
  alert(selectedServices)
  var url = '/api/VERSION/DATABALE/get?groupFilter='+ selectedServices + '&f_own='+ f_own  +'&f_research='+ f_research
  console.log('new URL'+url);
  table.ajax.url(url).load();
  table.ajax.reload();


});
```

I dont getting any error, but it not change date in my datatable too, when i combine my js code

Any idea how to solve it? all help will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly keeps you from combining the logic? If you think there is any kind of issue, what have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: i try combine bot function in one, but  i really bad in js, logic from python not help me a lot . Some example or something like what it will help me a lot.

Comment: Please share your attempts, and the errors you are facing

Comment: I update my post, maybe its helps to help me

Comment: `$('.selectpicker').on('change'); or ('input[name="checkboxGroup1"]')` is not valid - this won't trigger anything on changing `.selectpicker`

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements?

Comment: One function click another on change so idk or this example work

Comment: On this example i get ```Uncaught ReferenceError: or is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>```

Comment: Yeah, you will receive an error because `or` is not defined as anything. Have you even tried to adapt something from the linked post?

Comment: I try do something like what  ```$('.selectpicker').add('input[name="checkboxGroup1"]').on('click change', function(){``` thank you for your help