# How to do, if multi value change then event occur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value from these two id after they changed. How to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#Send").change(function(e){
        alert(this.value);
    });

    $("#Receive").change(function(e){
        alert(this.value);
    })

})
```

I want something like

```
if( #send change && #receive change ){
    var send
    var receive
}
```

Actually, I want to see if both values of #send & #receive are changed or not. If both value are changed then I want to receive their value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, do you want to get both values after they have BOTH been triggered or just when one of them triggers?

Answer (score 0):

**You can so something below**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var oldSend = $("#Send").val();
  var oldReceive = $("#Receive").val();
$("#Send, #Receive").change(function(e){
    
    var _t = $(this);
    /*if(_t.attr('id') == 'Send'){
        console.log('Send ' + _t.val() );
    } else if('#Receive'){
        console.log('Receive ' + _t.val() );
    }*/
    
    if(oldSend != $("#Send").val() && oldReceive != $("#Receive").val()){
      console.log('changedd ', _t.val())
    }
    

});


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Send">
<input type="text" id="Receive">
```

Comment: I want if both value change then only run a function. How to do that?

Comment: how does both value change at same time?

Comment: I suspect it's a language issue and OP wants to know: when both have changed

Comment: @freedomn-m yes,

Comment: Actually, I want to see if both values of #send & #receive  are changed or not. If both value are changed then I want to receive their value.

Comment: @user7252501 put the above wording in your question

Comment: i think you should store old value first in variable, and on change of any input need to compare and both value not same to old one, then make any conditional things. what do you thing @freedomn-m

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I thought you were already updating your answer to do that :)

Comment: @freedomn-m updated, but i dont think both value change at same time.

Comment: No, they won't change at the same time, but I don't think OP wants that - they want to know when both have been changed - which your updated code shows.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities to do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Send, #Receive').change(function(e){
 alert(this.value);
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Send">
<input type="text" id="Receive">
```

Or you could do it like that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Send').add('#Receive').change(function(e){
  alert(this.value);
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Send">
<input type="text" id="Receive">
```

Comment: I want after both value changes then run a function