# Multipal Vars to One onChange Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have tried a search but could not find an answer to my problem..
Im not very good with Javascript or JQuery so please be gentle with me lol

I have a form with multipal fields and what im tryin to do is hide a button when one of the fields has been changed.

I understand this is a OnChange type event but not sure how to go about if one of multipal fields have been changed to then hide the element

Heres what I have so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var opt1 = document.getElementById('BorderRange');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('bs');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('tb');
var opt4 = document.getElementById('wf');



opt1.onchange = function() {
   document.getElementById('pf').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

So this code works if one of the fields has been changed ("BorderRange") but is there a simple way of linking all vars to one onchange function?

Something like `opt1.onchange && opt2.onchange && opt3.onchange = function()` for example

many thanks

Comment: also: [jQuery same click event for multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313373/jquery-same-click-event-for-multiple-elements). Or the more general [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation#:~:text=Event%20delegation%20is%20handling%20an,on%20elements%20within%20the%20container.)

Comment: Via the link that someone kindly shared this solved my problem - Many thanks! `$('#invent1, #invent2, #invent3').change(function () {
   // Do magical things
});
`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `change` event listener to the form. Event bubbling will cause this to be triggered when any of the inputs in the form are changed.

```
document.getElementById("yourformID").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById('pf').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this, I will keep this idea for future ref, I have been given a link to another answer which told me exactly what i needed - thank you again!